# How to activate AP mode in configuration files?

Tags: freebsd

I am using here FreeBSD 11.1; I am putting together a test system,  and activating an AP mode in a Ralink wifi card with:

```
ifconfig wlan0 create wlandev run0 wlanmode hostap
ifconfig wlan0 inet 192.168.2.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 ssid UNITI mode 11g channel 1
```

(yeah, I do know I can use 5GHz but it is not my immediate concern).

My question is, how may I configure this in boot time files/rc.conf?

The 2nd line is pretty obvious I can create in `rc.conf`:

```
ifconfig_wlan0="inet 192.168.2.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 ssid UNITI mode 11g channel 1"
```

However I have no idea how to configure the hostap mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up putting in `/etc/rc.conf`:

```
wlans_run0="wlan0"
create_args_wlan0="wlanmode hostap"
ifconfig_wlan0="inet 192.168.2.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 ssid XXXXX mode 11g channel 1"
```

It worked.